# Find out how many elements contain numbers in array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out how many elements in an array of Twitter handles contain a number, but I can't figure it out.

I've tried this:

```
users = ["@jcunniet","@PaulLampon","@Aziliz31","@ssoumier","@marionsouzeau","@gaellombart","@bendarag" ...]

n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

puts " #{users.sum { |s| s.count(n.to_s) }} handle contain a number"
```

Comment: I suggest creating a "predicate" (a function which returns a boolean) that can test one handle, to see if it contains a number. Then, use that predicate in the code you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count how many elements in an array meet a certain condition, use [`Array#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-count) with a block that checks the condition:

```
users = ["@jcunniet", "@PaulLampon", "@Aziliz31", "@ssoumier", "@marionsouzeau", "@gaellombart", "@bendarag"]

users.count {|user| user =~ /[0-9]/ }
# => 1
```

This is preferable to methods like `Array#grep` because it doesn't initialize an intermediate array.

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/ScentedDiscreteCables

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a really easy way to scan a list and see how many of the strings contain at least one number:

```
users = %w[ @jcunniet @PaulLampon @Aziliz31 @ssoumier @marionsouzeau @gaellombart @bendarag ]

users.grep(/\d/)
# => ["@Aziliz31"]
```

Now if you want to know how many there are, in terms of count:

```
puts '%d handle contain a number' % users.grep(/\d/).length
```

That `/\d/` is a *regular expression*. These can get really complicated but this one just means "a digit". Regular expressions are incredibly powerful so don't be intimidated by them, spending some time learning how they work can lead to really compact solutions like this.

There's a lot in your original code that seems to be based on mistaken assumptions. For example, see what `n.to_s` does:

```
n= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
n.to_s
# => "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]"
```

That's a pretty ugly string and [`count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-count) is not going to be able to make use of that as that string will never occur inside a Twitter handle.

Likewise, `sum` wants to add up things, though it doesn't seem necessary here since there's nothing to add.

Ruby has a *lot* of tools to help you out. The first challenge is in narrowing down which ones you use to the appropriate ones. The next step is to broaden your tools to include more exotic ones like `sum`. Take it step by step and you'll be fine.

Comment: Amazing! thank you, man! exactly what i need for the next step of my exercice haha

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Simple Method Chain

In Ruby, you can use a method chain to have [Enumerable#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) to return the number of elements found by [Enumerable#grep](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep). For example:

```
users.grep(/\d/).count
#=> 1
```

There are certainly other ways to perform this task, but this code is short, simple, and easy to read. In this case, chaining methods also seems more logical and idiomatic than passing a block to the #count method, but it all depends on the semantics of what you're really trying to express in your code.

### Include Unicode Support

Less pretty, but including Unicode support:

```
users.grep(/\p{Nd}/).count
#=> 1
```

This doesn't matter for your provided example, but it might matter in real-world code, especially if your arrays are built dynamically or include sanitized user input.